# Using MKMapView, how can I center and zoom in on a coordinate as much as possible?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an MKMapView with various annotations. On tapping an annotation, I want the map to center and zoom in on that annotation as much as possible.

Using `mapView.setCenter` works to set the center, but not to zoom in.

Using `mapView.setRegion` with some region I define with my desired center location and span sort of works, but the span I set is largely arbitrary, and when it's too small, it seems that the mapView defaults to some other larger span from what I can see.

Is there a way for me to center on a specified location and zoom in as much as possible on that location programatically?

Comment: What do you mean by `zoom in as much as possible`? Do you have any conditions for zooming? Or just like, exactly zero meters from that annotation coordinate.

Comment: @son there seems to maximum zoom level on devices where the user cannot physically zoom in anymore. I want to programatically zoom in to that level with a specified center coordinate. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can make the span exactly meters from center location. Try this:

```swift
private func zoomIn(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, with metersFromCenter: Int = 0) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location,
                                    latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: metersFromCenter)!,
                                    longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: metersFromCenter)!)
    mapView.setRegion(mapView.regionThatFits(region), animated: true)
}
```

Output here, this is the maximum zoom level. **Notice that this span level does not match with Apple Map default**.

[image]